# Change default position of Dialog Windows KDE 4.10

Tags: kde, kde4

I have KDE 4.10 running on my system, today when configure to work with two monitors top/bottom i get the surprise that modal dialogs show in the middle of two monitors, example the Intellij's Search everywhere dialog.

this is annoying, how i can chage the default position of this for every dialog of this type

Answer (score 0):

You can influence the window placement as follows: Start System Settings and then go to `Window Behavior` > `Window Behavior` > `Advanced` tab. Therein, you can configure the `Placement` of the windows. The combo box has detailed `What's This` information (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, then click on the combo box).